# How to create a scale operation which produce result in a specific range?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

First of all, I'm not sure what what to call what I would like help creating so please bear with me.

I want to create a system with 2 inputs x and y, f(xy). In which both x and y are in range. For example;

- x is 0 <= x <= 10
- y is -5 <= y <=5

I also want f(xy) to returns in the same range as x.

F(xy) will scale x with the input y in a way so that x will scaled down if y<0 or x will be scaled up if y>0 in the most sensible way that the amount it scaled up/down is according to the magnitude given by y.

So if y=-5, any value of x will be scaled down to 0 in which f(xy) returns 0. 
And if y=5 any value of x will be scaled up to 10 in which f(xy) also returns 0.

Another Example, I want to scale up x by using y=2. Lets assume we already have the function. I used the function to scale up 2 values of x. Say x1 and x2. x1 is 2 and x2 is 6.

Plunging f(x1,y) say we returns 4 and f(x2,y) we returns 7. So if the value x we choose is close to the upper limit and we scale it up, the change of x is smaller than if we chose a small x (I hope this explains why the function is dependent to x)

What are the basic concept used to make this possible?

Thank you in advance

Comment: It seems unclear what you want to do. The notation $f(x,y)$ suggests a result depending on both $x$ and $y$, whereas you say you want the result in the same range as that of $x$. Maybe you really want a simple function $g(y)$ so that the numbers in the $y$ range wind up somewhere in the range of $x$... if so that can be done by rescaling the $y$ interval if it has different length as the $x$ interval, and then shifting by adding or subtracting a constant.

Comment: yeah firstly I apologize for my effort of explaining seems so ambiguous. But the function I was trying to look for is really do dependent of x (and y). I put up some example for you, maybe it can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't easily tell you the basic concepts except to say "linear interpolation". But here's an answer to your question.

Let's suppose that 
$$
a \le x \le b \\
c \le y \le d
$$
are the ranges for $x$ and $y$. If we define
$$
t = \frac{y-c}{d-c}
$$
then $t$ tells you how far along the $c$-to-$d$ range $y$ is: when $y$ is $c$, $t$ is 0; when $y$ is $d$, $t = 1$. And when $y$ is the average of $c$ and $d$, $t$ is $1/2$.

Let 
$$
s = 1-t
$$
This works the same way as $t$, except that it's $0$ at $c$ and $1$ at $d$.

Now we can define
\begin{align}
f(x, y) &= t^2 b + 2st x + s^2 a \\
 &= \left(\frac{y-c}{d-c}\right)^2 a + 2\frac{y-c}{d-c}\left(1-\frac{y-c}{d-c}\right) x + \left(1-\frac{y-c}{d-c}\right)^2 b \\
\end{align}

When you plug in $y = c$, you get

\begin{align}
f(x, c) &=  \left(\frac{c-c}{d-c}\right)^2 b + 2\frac{c-c}{d-c}\left(1-\frac{c-c}{d-c}\right) x + \left(1-\frac{c-c}{d-c}\right)^2 a \\
&=  0 \cdot b + 2\cdot 0 \cdot 1 \cdot  x + 1 a \\
&= a
\end{align}

Similar,
\begin{align}
f(x, d) &= b
\end{align}

So as $y$ goes from $c$ to $d$, the function (of $x$) ranges from a constant $a$ to a constant $b$. When $y$ is the average of $c$ adn $d$, $s$ and $t$ are both 1/2; in that case we get
\begin{align}
f(x, \frac{c+d}{2}) 
&= \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 b + 2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 x + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 a \\
&= \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 b + 2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 x + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 a \\
&= \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \left[b + 2 x +  a \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{4} \left[b + 2 x +  a \right] \\
\end{align}

which, as $x$ goes from $a$ to $b$, ranges between $1/4$ of the way from $a$ to $b$ up to $3/4$ of the way from $a$ to $b$.

If you want the halfway case to actually send $[a, b]$ to *all* of $[a, b]$, you'll need to deal with a function that has "cases" in it.

Comment: Thank You, sir!.. can I play the '2' constant in the 2stx part? I wonder what influence it will give to the result if I change the constant

Comment: Critical to this design is that $s + t = 1$, so that $1 = (s + t)^2 = s^2 + 2st + t^2 = 1$. In other words, my formula represents a weighted average of three functions: the constant $x \mapsto a$; the constant $x \mapsto b$, and the identity function $x \mapsto x$, with weights $s^2$, $t^2$, and $2st$, respectively. If you increase the "2", you may get a function that sends some points of the $[a,b]$ interval to points outside that interval; that'd be bad.

Comment: sorry for late reply, its finals week on my uni.. 
I see, I reckon this also only works for other even-pascal polynomial (e.g. 121, 14641) is it not? and also the higher degree even-polynom you picked, its getting more steep.. I mean the closer the scale factor value to the limit of the range will give a greater magnitude difference to x, right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying, but the idea I've used repeatedly is that if $(s + t) = 1$, then an $sx + ty$ combination of numbers $x$ and $y$ lies somewhere bwtween them, at one end when $s = 0$, at the other when $t = 0$. You can also apply this idea to $(s+t)^2 = 1$, or $(s+t)^3 = 1$ to get more complex combinations that sum up nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following algorithm when plotting signal data in Windows:

Starting conditions:

```
Scale factor: 1.0
N samples: 0
Max sample: 0
Min sample: 0
Plot range: (Max - Min): 0
Plot area (y): K pixels (depends on screen layout issues) 
Data changed: false
```

The assumption is that y=0 is at pixel K/2, and that data is symmetric

For each sample I do:

```
...add new point y to display array
changed = false;
if(y > max) {max = y; changed = true;}
if(y < min) {min = y; changed = true;}
if(changed)
   { /* recompute scaling factor */
    int dy;
    if(max > -min)
      dy = max;
    else
      dy = -min;
    if(dy * scalingfactor) > K / 2)
       { /* rescale */

        scalingfactor = (double)(K / 2) / (double)dy;
        requestredraw();  // in Windows, InvalidateRect(NULL);
       } /* rescale */
    } /* recompute scaling factor */
  else
    { /* just draw new point */
     ...whatever it takes
    } /* just draw new point */
```

Note that I'm trying to recreate this from memory, so no guarantees as to its absolute correctness.  This is intended for use in an algorithm which is adding points in realtime.  Note that you can use the same algorithm to iterate over a set of existing data points, and because the "requestredraw" is requesting a deferred drawing, there will be only one redraw actually done.  In addition, you will need to run this over your dataset whenever the window you are plotting in gets resized (if you allow that), and I am assuming that X-scaling, if needed, is handled in an analogous fashion.

I don't follow your detailed explanation;  this is a function that takes a value y and stores it in an array used to plot the function, and later the plotting algorithm computes y'= f(y) where f(y) returns (int) ((double)y * scalingfactor).  So you don't compute the actual y-position of the plot until you are drawing the graph, because the instantaneous mapping depends on external values that may not be known until drawing time.

The plotting on a screen is a special case of constraining to a limit.  If you want to increase the loudness of an audio sample without clipping, you have to make a complete pass across the data to make sure your scaling factor (say, 1.5) when used on 16-bit audio samples does not produce a value >32767 or <-32768, and if it does, you have to compute the maximum scaling that will work, and tell the user that the value provided will result in clipping.  I would tend to indicate on the volume control where the clipping region begins; to do this, you scan the file, and compute the maximum scaling factor that puts the loudest sound at 32767 (or -32768), and if the user requests a higher value, the control either turns red or has a red area at its high end, or both.  You must also make sure that a scaled sample does not exceed the 16-bit range (or 8-bit range, or 24-bit range; I've been using 16-bit for all this discussion), e.g.

```
int32 newlevel = (int32)((double) sample * scalingfactor);
if (newlevel > 32767) newlevel = 32767;
if (newlevel < -32768) newlevel = -32768;
```

If there is clipping being done, you can't just multiply and store the resulting bits; you will get nonsense coming out (if you don't believe me, try it)